# Difference between "Where is" and "How to get there"

Tags: word-usage

In my article, I would like to answer the following questions "Where is XYZ?" and "How to get to XYZ?"
Where XYZ is a location such as hiking trail. What is the difference between those two statements and is it better to combine these two statements together?

Comment: You've confused the issue a bit by framing one phrase as a question and the other as a statement. If you want them both to be questions then the second needs to be "How do you (or I) get there?" In an article discussing a place or establishment these questions are _rhetorical_ since you lnow the answer and you're about to tell the reader. Is there anything wrong with using rhetorical qusstions like that? No, they're very useful. (See what I did there?)

Answer (score 2):

The usage and concepts of these two questions are formally different but may overlap, depending on context. I will illustrate this by two examples.

Where is the hottest place in the Earth? It is in the centre of the planet. How to get there? It is impossible. The context of these two questions makes clear that knowing where something is does not tell you how to get there.

Where is the the train station? It is two blocks ahead and one block to the right. How to get there? Go two blocks ahead and one block to the right. In this case the context is such that the answer to each formally different question is the same.

Briefly put, the equivalence of answers does not imply the equivalence of questions.